# Choosing an authentication provider for a background console application

Tags: azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I need to build a console application (using .NET Framework 4.8) which can read email messages from a single mailbox in our company's Azure-hosted instance. The application will be launched periodically by Windows Task Scheduler and will be calling the Microsoft Graph API. I know how to do all of this.

My question relates to the authentication for the app. The options I think are appropriate are the [authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) and the [client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider), but there are problems with both.

The authorization code flow is very much designed for applications with which the user interacts. The user tries to access the application, it makes them login, grant the application the required permissions (scopes), and the access token which is ultimately obtained from Azure is used to make subsequent calls to the Graph API for data. The problem is that this application will not be particularly interactive. The idea is that the app will be configured once (e.g. by supplying it with an access token) and then will just run by itself from thereon.

The client credential flow, therefore, probably seems more appropriate. [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview) recommends this authentication provider for *"Desktop applications (like Windows services on Windows or daemon processes on Linux) that perform batch jobs, or an operating system service that runs in the background"*. Perfect. Except that, as far as I can see, an application with a token for use with the client credential flow (with the `Mail.Read` scope) can access the mailbox of *any* user in our organisation. For this reason, our admins are understandably reluctant to authorize such an app.  This issue of extreme sensitivity for apps of this nature is highlighted in the documentation linked above. We would control which mailboxes are accessed in the app's code and strictly limit access to both the code and the server on which it runs, but the code is still *out there*.

A workaround, towards which I'm leaning, is a hack in which I make the user go through the authorization code flow once to obtain an access token and a refresh token, both of which I store in a database along with the access token's expiry time. I then have the app's code check whether the authorization code has expired each time it runs and, if so, use the refresh token to get new tokens and save them to the database.

This feels very much like an anti-pattern, but it works. It allows the application to run independently of a user, and were the access code to be compromised despite our strict measures to protect it, only a single mailbox would be vulnerable. Nevertheless, I'd be interested to know if there's a better way to achieve this which is in line with the standard patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The client id and secret are what I like to call the Keys to the Kingdom, and cannot be scoped to a single box as you desire.

Allow me to suggest an alternative approach: create a Flow or Logic App to pull emails from that inbox, and send it to a service that will process it and do the rest. Maybe an Azure queue with an Azure Function, or just an API listening somewhere, or whatever you like.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion and I've just been able to achieve more or less exactly what I want using a Power Automate flow. I'll leave this open for a few days as your answer is more of an alternative (a very good one!) than a direct answer to the question, to see what other suggestions people have. Thanks!